# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed

Tags: java, jsp, executable-jar

I have created a normal .JSP page with f tags and h tags. But when I'm running it on the server, this is the exception I am getting. I think that I have missed out on some JAR files.

If you could please mention the necessary JARs it would be great for me, since there are a  million of them.

Thanks.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
```

Comment: This namespace `http://java.sun.com/jsf/core` refers to JSF. Are you targeting to JSF 1.x?

Comment: Is the name space required in order to run the .jsp? I am targeting to JSP.

Comment: The exception itself is rather surprised to me. It is not required. I merely assumed that you might be targeting to JSF 1.x (which I am completely unaware of) which uses JSP(X) as a view technology.

Comment: What is not required?

Comment: The exception message basically implies that your project or something else requires a JSF dependency lurking somewhere which is unavailable hence, the exception. It is also likely to be a bug in the server which you are using.

Comment: Okay. So can you please suggest a solution to the problem?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know. Otherwise, I would have already mentioned in the very first comment. I am also not familiar with the old, buggy, poorly designed and EOL JSF 1.x dinosaur, if it were to be associated with the concrete problem somewhere knowingly and/or unknowingly.

Answer (score 0):

the jstl jar is not included in many frameworks. To fix it, declares the jstl dependency like this in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Also if you dont have pom.xml you download a jar from here..
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstljar.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is an instruction manually add JSTL library to Tomcat7 classpath. Most likely works for any Tomcat release but T7 is what I use at the moment.
[Download javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.4.jar file](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1002239527)
[Download javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar file](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C707331597)

Put both files to `$tomcat/lib` folder making accessible by all web applications. First file is Apache implementation of JSTL specification. Second file is an interface api file for that specification.

If you are missing JavaServerFaces libraries [see this tutorial.](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/)

Comment: I downloaded both the jars and ran the jsp file. However the same exception is showing up.

Comment: You are most likely missing JavaServerFaces(jsf) libraries, see linked tutorial link for what's needed in Tomcat.